# how to compare two strings without using string library functions in c#

Tags: c#, helper

how can I compare two strings without using string library functions in c#
i have wrote this code but I'm not sure if it's good or not

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string x, b;
            x = Console.ReadLine();
            b = Console.ReadLine();
            if (x == b)
                Console.WriteLine("The length of both strings are equal and also, both strings are 
                 equal");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("The length of both strings are not equal and also, both strings are 
                 not equal");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You *are* using string functions here - specifically, the `String.Equals` function

Comment: Why do you think that `==` is not a library function? Look [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8307d03426b56fe1,references) (scroll a bit upwards)

Comment: I'm curious why you'd want to "roll your own code" to replace what comes built in to do what you're asking.

Comment: Because he/she is a student that has to solve this problem. What you need @jax is to use loops (hint check out the `for` loop). Create a static function that takes two string arguments a and b and returns true if they match or false otherwise.

Comment: i just start learning c# and the doctor gave this as a homework :)

Comment: Side note: _"The length of both strings are not equal"_ You do _not_ know that.

Comment: thank u  @MihailShishkov

Comment: If you're curious, you can look through the string equality implementation in mscorlib: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,364

Comment: @MihailShishkov The use of indexing on a string is *also* a library function. Or how do you define library anyway? Oh dear...